# Prove or disprove that where $a, b \in Z$, the number a+b is even if and only if a-b is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove or disprove that where $a, b \in Z$, the number a+b is even if and only if a-b is even.

Can some help me improve on this or check it please?

If $a + b$ is even, then there is some number $k \in Z$ such that $a + b = 2k$.

If $a - b$ is odd, then there is some number $m \in Z$ such that $a - b = 2m +1$.
$a + b = a - b + 2b = 2m + 1 + 2b = 2(m + b) +1$. This is an odd number.

Now try for $a - b$ is even.
If $a - b$ is even, then there is a number $m \in Z$ such that $a - b = 2m$.
$a + b = a - b + 2b = 2b + 2m = 2(b + m)$. This is an even number.

Therefore, $a + b$ is even if and only if $a - b$ is even.

Comment: Always try a few examples. $a=1, b=1$ is the simplest and easily resolves the problem.

Comment: Also, can you comment: your question is $1-b$ but at the end of your post you put in $a-b$, those are different questions.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Are you looking at $a-b$ or $1-b$?

Comment: In the 4th line you have written $a-b+2b=2m+1+2k$.  How did $2b$ become $2k$?

Comment: Yes, edited. Thanks, sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I should probably be defining b and a, individually. Not just a + b. I could probably have just left 2b as 2b, as it represents an even number.

Comment: we have $a+b=a-b+2b\implies a+b\equiv a-b \pmod 2$

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does the triple equal sign mean?

Comment: Ok, I have found, so you're saying that $a + b$ and $a - b$ have the same remainder when divided by 2. Let me cogitate on that.

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ n\!+\!2b $ even $\iff n\,$ even. OP is special case $\, n = a-b\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a+b \text{ even}\iff a \text{ and}\space b \text{ are both odd or even}\iff a-b \text{ even}$$

Comment: Wow, you took one line to say what I was trying to say in a paragraph @Piquito.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a+b = a-b +2b$ and so $a+b$ and $a-b$ differ by an even number. Therefore, they have the same parity.

Answer (score 1):

Clarity is in the eye of the beholder. I like the following sequence of pairwise equivalent statements

1. $a+b$ is even.
2. $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: a+b = 2k$.
3. $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: a-b = 2(k-b)$.
4. $\exists h \in \mathbb{Z}: a-b = 2h$.
5. $a-b$ is even.

Depending on the expectations of the class, this may be notational overkill.

Answer (score 0):

We have $a+b$ even iff $a+b=2k$ for some $k$ iff $a+b-2b = 2k-2b=2(k-b)$ even iff $a-b=2(k-b)$ even.